Z3:Invalid timeout parameter
A timeout parameter was set for Z3 solver, and after performing thousands of solving, it was found that the timeout parameter was invalid and the solving process would not stop at the scheduled time.
We used the Z3 C API to set the timeout parameter and some other parameters.
timeout_param = Z3_mk_params(ctx);
Z3_params_inc_ref(ctx, timeout_param);
Z3_params_set_uint(ctx, timeout_param, Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "timeout"), 20000);
                     
Z3_global_param_set("model.partial", "true");
Z3_global_param_set("smt.ematching", "true");
Z3_global_param_set("smt.mbqi.max_iterations", "10000");
Z3_global_param_set("rewriter.hi_fp_unspecified", "true");

Specifically, we recorded the time of each solving and found that it was performed strictly according to the time set by the parameter. However, the solving that went wrong took tens of times longer than the parameter.
What are the possible reasons for this?

Timeouts in z3 is rather a tricky issue. Here's what one of the developers said before: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5568#issuecomment-927139409
Quoting from there:

Not all activities can be safely interrupted. Z3 internally polls for
whether there is a cancelation/timeout/resource excess state. The
polling is only performed safe places. For example, if it performs a
"push", which can be in response to an internal or external action, it
cannot be safely interrupted because the state is not safely
backtrackable. Based on the high-level report I have to assume it is
due to the solver being set into a state where it cannot be
interrupted.

So, it is entirely possible that your use case falls into one of the cases where z3 does not poll.
If you reduce your problem and create an easy reproducer, you can post it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/ and get some feedback.
If you really want to stop solving completely, using something like setrlimit might be more appropriate. Alternatively, you can start a separate thread for the solver, and kill it from the parent if it doesn't return after a certain amount of time. It all depends on what you want to do.
